# Packaged Python program for Mac will not run when downloaded

Tags: python, macos, file-upload, compression, runtime-error

I have Python program that I packaged with py2app so that the program `query_agent.py` became `query_agent.app`. I have a Java program that launches `query_agent.app` with the following command:

> open ./query_agent.app --args abs_path1 abs_path2

, where `abs_path1` and `abs_path2` are string arguments.

I put everything in a folder and when I launch the JAR that eventually launches `query_agent.app`, everything runs perfectly as expected.

So I zip this folder so I can distribute it to others. Before sending, I put the zip on a flash drive and unzip it on another Mac computer to test it. Again, the program works as expected even when unzipped.

However, when I send the zip as a message attachment in an email, or upload the zip to a file hosting site like MediaFire, the program no longer works when unzipped. When I unzip the downloaded zip file on any Mac computer, right-click and open, I get the message:

> query_agent Error

When I open the console, it shows the cause of the error:

[image: query_agent Error]

The `STATS_FILE_LOCATION` points to a file that I am trying to write to. This file is located at query_agent.app/Contents/Resources/resources. As a reminder, this works fine if I use the version of the zip before it was uploaded.

It appears that the main error is shown in the last line as

> OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'resources/status.txt'

The first thing I notice is that it is finding my source files in the /private/var/folder/... location. I believe this a temp location, which may be why I am getting the "read-only file system" error. I never intended for anything to be read from or written to any location outside of my main applications folder.

I also get the message:

> Detected missing constraints for <private>.  It cannot be placed because there are not enough constraints to fully define the size and origin. Add the missing constraints, or set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES and constraints will be generated for you. If this view is laid out manually on macOS 10.12 and later, you may choose to not call [super layout] from your override. Set a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS to debug. This error will only be logged once.

So my question is: **Why doesn't my program work if I upload it, download it, unzip it, and then try to run it?**

It works before the upload on any Mac computer I put it on, so the fact that it gets zipped is not the issue. I hope that these obscure error messages can provide some hints to why this is happening. Any help with solving this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and can confirm that it doesn't seem to be package dependency or permission dependent. The packaged app can be freely moved and run on other machines via physical media, even if zipped, but as found by OP, will not run if distributed 'over the air' - with the exception of same room Mac to Mac AirDrop.